# i want to add markers on google map to make polygon

Tags: android, google-maps

this is the code

i have tried multiple times to add marker to map please guide .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements OnMapClickListener, OnMapLongClickListener, OnMarkerClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
private GoogleMap myMap;

Location myLocation;
TextView tvLocInfo;

boolean markerClicked;
PolygonOptions polygonOptions;
Polygon polygon;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvLocInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locinfo);

    FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    MapFragment myMapFragment
            = (MapFragment) myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    myMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);



        return;


    }

    myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    myMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);


    markerClicked = false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_legalnotices:
            String LicenseInfo = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo(
                    getApplicationContext());
            AlertDialog.Builder LicenseDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LicenseDialog.setTitle("Legal Notices");
            LicenseDialog.setMessage(LicenseInfo);
            LicenseDialog.show();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable SUCCESS",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, RQS_GooglePlayServices);
    }

}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    tvLocInfo.setText(point.toString());
    myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));

    markerClicked = false;
}

@Override
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());
    myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString()));

    markerClicked = false;
}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    if (markerClicked) {

        if (polygon != null) {
            polygon.remove();
            polygon = null;
        }

        polygonOptions.add(marker.getPosition());
        polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.RED);
        polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.BLUE);
        polygon = myMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
    } else {
        if (polygon != null) {
            polygon.remove();
            polygon = null;
        }

        polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions().add(marker.getPosition());
        markerClicked = true;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    myMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        return;
    }



}
```

}

i got this code from GoogleMapV2 but i am not able to make markers on google map

how can i add marker to google map

please help

Comment: You add one as any marker in the polygon. Start with the top one for an instance. Then you calculate the position of the next one based on the amount of markers and the past position.

Answer (score 0):

Here I call `map` as `id`

```
var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: latlng,
             map: map,
             title:"fggfh.Pvt.Ltd"
             });
```